# Receive (recv) full request (e.g. curl HTTP)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

How should this be done?

I want to receive a (rather long) HTTP request and cannot get this to work.
The problem: Without flags, `recv` does not read the whole message. I guess this is normal behavior. From what I understand using the `MSG_WAITALL` flag causes it to block until everything is received. However, in that case the call blocks forever (until I ctrl+c the client (curl) process.

Below there is a (still lengthy, but rather minimal) example snippet.
Sorry it mixes C and C++ style but I wanted to avoid own errors and sticked largely to example code with as few modifications as possible.

```
// Example largely based on: beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html
// Mixes c-style and c++ due to my modifications.
// Only intended to reproduce a problem.
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define PORT "7004"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10     // how many pending connections queue will hold

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
  if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
  }

  return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
  int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
  struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
  socklen_t sin_size;
  struct sigaction sa;
  int yes=1;
  char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  int rv;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

  if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
  }

  // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
  for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                         p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
      perror("server: socket");
      continue;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                   sizeof(int)) == -1) {
      perror("setsockopt");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
      close(sockfd);
      perror("server: bind");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

  if (p == NULL)  {
    fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

  while(1) {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
              get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
              s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

    const uint EASILY_ENOUGH = 1000000;
    char* buffer = new char[EASILY_ENOUGH + 1];
    auto bytesRead = recv(new_fd, buffer, EASILY_ENOUGH, MSG_WAITALL); // FREEZES UNTIL I KILL THE CLIENT
    // auto bytesRead = recv(new_fd, buffer, EASILY_ENOUGH, 0); // DOES NOT READ FULL REQUEST
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
      perror("recv");
      close(new_fd);
      continue;
    }
    buffer[bytesRead] = 0;

    printf("bytes read: %ld\n", bytesRead);
    printf("request: %s\n", buffer);
    delete[] buffer;

    std::string content = "some content.";
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" << "Content-Length: " << content.size() << "\r\n"
       << "Connection: close\r\n" << "Content-Type: " << "plain/text"
       << "; charset=" << "utf-8" << "\r\n"
       << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" << "\r\n" << "\r\n" << content;

    std::string response = os.str();
    printf("Response has size: %ld\n", response.size());
    auto bytesSent = send(new_fd, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0);
    printf("Method send claims it has sent %ld bytes\n", bytesSent);
    close(new_fd);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The curl resquest i used:

```
curl 'http://<myhost>:7004/___THE START___jsondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwasondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwasondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwasondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwa___THE END'
```

With `MSG_WAITALL` my server produces the output:

```
server: waiting for connections...
server: got connection from <my ip>
```

and hangs, once I CTRL+C curl it progresses with:

```
bytes read: 6379
request: GET /___THE START___jsondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwasondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwasondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwasondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwa___THE END HTTP/1.1
Host: <myhost>:7004
User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
Accept: */*


Response has size: 144
Method send claims it has sent 144 bytes
```

Without `MSG_WAITALL` and the same request, the server produces the output:

```
server: waiting for connections...
server: got connection from <my ip>
bytes read: 1448
request: GET /___THE START___jsondsadasdasdzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwaghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewjfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiwehfoewhfiuewhfiewhfhfiuewhfiwehfiuewwehgurwadzughjdssftzghuijerdftzghujiesdhufdewojfoewfhoiw
Response has size: 144
Method send claims it has sent 144 bytes
```

And curl does not receive the HTTP response.
However, a shorter request properly receives the response:

```
curl 'http://myhost:7004/___THE START___THE END__'
> some content.
```

And the server properly received the full request:

```
server: got connection from <my ip>
bytes read: 128
request: GET /___THE START___THE END__ HTTP/1.1
Host: <myhost>:7004
User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
Accept: */*


Response has size: 144
Method send claims it has sent 144 bytes
```

I do understand that it is normal that not all TCP packets arrive right away. However, what is the correct way for me to assemble the full request? I also tried non-blocking variants but usually ran into situations where no more data was ready for reading. If necessary I can produce sample code for this, similarly.

PS: The problem manifests when request length and connection badness exceed a threshold. I cannot reproduce it on my own machine with queries to localhost, and depending on my connection, the request length where problems start to manifest varies.

Comment: You cannot "mix C and C++" in the same source code! They are different languages and different compilers.

Comment: you can still mix the style, i.e. use cstrings in c++, but not exclusively. i don't think it is a good idea, but i stated my reasons. either way, this is nothing to do with teh question

Comment: No, but with tagging which justifies a comment about site-rules. And using C coding style does not mean the code has the same semantics! Try `static const int i = 10; static a[i];` in both languages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is a protocol, it has structure and rules to it.  Read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), particularly  [Section 4 "HTTP Message"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4).

Your `recv` code is not doing anything to follow the protocol at all.  You can't just blindly read an arbitrary buffer of data and expect it to be the complete HTTP request correctly.  You have to read the request according to the rules of the protocol.  Specifically, you need to:

- read a CRLF delimited line of text. This will contain the requested method, resource, and HTTP version.
- then read a variable length list of CRLF delimited request headers. The list is terminated by a CRLF CRLF sequence.
- then analyze the request method and headers to determine whether the request has an entity body. If so, the headers will tell you how it is encoded over the connection (see  [Section 4.4 "Message Length"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4)), so you know how it needs to be read and when you need to stop reading.
- then process the completed request, and send your response.
- then close the connection, unless either:
- the request asked for HTTP 1.0 and `Connection: keep-alive` is present in the request headers.
- the request asked for HTTP 1.1+ and `Connection: close` is not present in the request headers.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, already. However, I cannot really figure out a good policy from that document. As I understand, I need to check that a message actually is HTTP and find its end. Is it enough to check if the message starts with a HTTP method? Can I discard the rest of a request once I read the HTTP/1. part or will my socket complain if there is still stuff ready for receiving?

Comment: You have to follow the rules correctly. The RFC is very clear about how the request is structured. Read the structure as defined. If the message is malformed, send an appropriate reply back, like 500, and close the socket. Otherwise, process the request as needed and send an appropriate reply back.